# iterative airflow execution

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have the following DAG with some simple tasks,

```
hour_list = [“0:00”, “1:00", “2:00”]

 for hour in hour_list:
    bash_op = BashOperator(
                task_id=‘task1_op1’+hour
                ,bash_command=“date”
                ,dag=dag
         )


    py_op = PythonOperator(
            task_id='doit’+hour,
            provide_context=True,
            python_callable=python_method,
            dag=dag)

    py_op.set_upstream(bash_op)
```

Now, I see the dag is executing in parallel for all the hours 0:00 to 2:00. It's an expected behaviour. But, I want to run the dags one hour after the other like the second hour execution is dependent on the first hour. I'm not sure any change in settings might help here. I appreciate your thoughts. thanks.

Comment: Do you want them to run in succession, as they complete, or do you want them to run in success at the specific time outlined by the `hour_list` variable?

Comment: My first requirement is to run dag in an iterative manner hour after hour. Also, I want to stop the iteration once the dag failed at a previous hour. thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason for not simply setting `DAG`'s `schedule_interval=timedelta(hours=1)`?

Comment: I want to run some tasks based for every hour within the DAG and finally run some tasks at the end of the day based on the DAG schedule (once a day). so, I may not set the hourly schedule at DAG level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the `airflow.operators.sensors.TimeSensor` "in between" the tasks. Something similar to the following:

```
from datetime import time

from airflow.operators.sensors import TimeSensor

[...]

for hour in ["00:00", "01:00", "02:00"]:
    TimeSensor(
        dag=dag,
        task_id="wait_{}".format(hour),
        target_time=time(*map(int, hour.split(":")))
    ) >> BashOperator(
        dag=dag,
        task_id="task1_op1_{}".format(hour),
        bash_command="date"
    ) >> PythonOperator(
        dag=dag,
        task_id="doit_{}".format(hour),
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=python_method
    )
```

Comment: But, If the date is in past, then the DAG start working in parallel for various hours. I want to work make it work hour by hour even if the date is a past date. so that, I will avoid consistencies in my processing.